# If a session cookie expires after maxAge despite user activity, wouldn't that affect user experience?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am a relatively new developer learning the MERN stack. Currently having problems with deciding on persistent login methods. With regards to express-sessions, I understand that setting the maxAge option will allow the browser to delete the cookie after said milliseconds.

However, this is despite user activity and can cause bad user experience. I also understand that there is a rolling option to allow for a new cookie every request. However, that introduces a security flaw since the cookie can be constantly refreshed.

Is there a set best practice for persistent logins/sessions?

Comment: which store are you using for storing your session to database?

Comment: @Naresh I am using mongodb

Comment: there are lots of [stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) that can help you to store/remove your session in the database. I'm not sure about the others but the [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) that I used automatically update the `maxAge`  everytime user interacts with the session.

Comment: @Naresh I see! However, does the cookie expire though? My concern is that the cookie will expire as the user is active so the session's expiry date updating won't help. Am I wrong with how it works?

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to use JWT tokens. You can create `active` and `refresh` tokens and set the `refresh` token to have a long expiration time.

Here's an [article](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) from Auth0 which provides a summary of JWT tokens and how to use `refresh` tokens to keep users authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply!! If an attacker can access the refresh token stored in cookies, won't the attacker be able to obtain a new access token?

Comment: @brycegoh Yes. That's why you should store refresh tokens in a secure location like a database protected by a firewall. You should validate and audit any requests that are made there. In the case that an attacker does breach your secure location, then you should immediately revoke all user tokens and require a new log in